# puppeteer page.goto api unable to load a URL

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, ts-jest, jest-puppeteer

I'm setting up integration test workflow in my current project. For that I'm using jest-puppeteer and writing test cases in typescript. But `await page.goto(url, {waitUntil:'networkidle2'})` is unable to load any URL. I have reproduced the issue please refer [this package](https://github.com/Dip686/jest-puppeteer-ts). https://github.com/Dip686/jest-puppeteer-ts

[image]

Comment: why are you importing puppeteer and redefining browser and page?

Comment: updated the redeclaration of variable, by importing puppeteer do u mean require statement in layout.test.ts  file?

Comment: if you're using jest-puppeteer you don't need to launch browser or create page.

Comment: @mbit, thanks, relaunching browser is breaking the flow, used the existing page instance provided by the jest-puppeteer working fine.